# Why is the search not picking this up?

Tags: support, search

I did this search: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?q=heiki&submit=search thru SO and thru the link provided. At this time, nothing pulled up. But if do this search: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?q=henki&submit=search it pulls up fine. Does the search only work on the questions and OP's post. Or does search all the words in a thread? Just curious.

Comment: Good idea. Just making sure I wasn't misunderstanding about how the site worked.

Comment: I'm seeing the same question in both search results now.  Are you?

Comment: Yep. I am. You are right. Thanks!

Comment: I would mark you as the correct answer. But there's no answer, lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can the search a little while to update with new posts.  Your post was submitted not long before your search query, so chances are it just hasn't updated yet.

Check back in a day and see if you still can't find your post.